# Why is useState not being updated?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am doing authorization on next-auth. I transfer the received session to the context, but it is updated only after the page is reloaded, before that the value is null

I did this

**layout.ts**

```
export default async function RootLayout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
  const session: Session | null = await getServerSession(authOptions)

  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <AuthProvider>
          <UserProvider user={session ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(session.user)) : null}>
            <Providers>
               {children}
            </Providers>
          </UserProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**UserProvider.ts**

```
'use client'

type LoginProps = {
  email: string
  password: string
}

type UserProviderProps = {
  user: IUser | null
  loginUser: (login: LoginProps) => Promise<void>
  setUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IUser | null>>
}

const UserContext = React.createContext<UserProviderProps>({} as UserProviderProps)

export const UserProvider: React.FC<{
  user: IUser | null
  children: React.ReactNode
}> = ({ user, children }) => {

  const router = useRouter()
  const [current_user, setUser] = React.useState<IUser | null>(user)

  async function loginUser(login: LoginProps) {
    await signIn('credentials', {...login, redirect: false})
    setUser({...user})
  }

  const value = React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
      user: current_user,
      loginUser,
      setUser,
    }
  }, [current_user])

  return <UserContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
}

export const useUser = () => React.useContext(UserContext)
```

in the browser console, if you check the user status during authorization, it is null, after refreshing the page, the data appears

Comment: `loginUser` and `setUser` are missing in the `useMemo` dependency array. That means that it keeps around the `loginUser` function as defined when it first mounted, which in turn will have a stale reference to `user` in the function body if called after initial mount. Possible it's not this, but that's a red flag.

Comment: How not, here they are const value = React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
      user: current_user,
      loginUser,
      setUser,
    }
  }, [current_user])